# Drawing borders between colors using shader and MonoGame

Tags: shader, monogame, fragment-shader

Today I decided to learn somthing about shader and already stuck. I'm writing for MonoGame in HLSL.  As I still have problems with language semantics, I don't understand why it is not working.
Image has many areas, each of other color. I want to draw border between those areas.

What I expect: if pixel is not on border, replace given color (this part is working fine if is alone) and if it is a border, set color red.

What I get: whole texture is red

Code:

```
#if OPENGL
    #define SV_POSITION POSITION
    #define VS_SHADERMODEL vs_3_0
    #define PS_SHADERMODEL ps_3_0
#else
    #define VS_SHADERMODEL vs_4_0_level_9_1
    #define PS_SHADERMODEL ps_4_0_level_9_1
#endif

sampler s0;
float4 selectedColor;

float4 PixelShaderFunction(float2 coords : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{      
    float4 currentColor = tex2D(s0, coords);
    float4 leftColor = tex2D(s0, coords - float2(1, 0));
    float4 rightColor = tex2D(s0, coords + float2(1, 0));
    float4 topColor = tex2D(s0, coords + float2(0, 1));
    float4 bottomColor = tex2D(s0, coords - float2(0, 1));
    
    bool isBorder = leftColor != currentColor ||
    rightColor != currentColor ||
        topColor != currentColor ||
        bottomColor != currentColor;
    
    if (isBorder)
    {
        currentColor = float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        bool isSame = (currentColor.r == selectedColor.r) && (currentColor.g == selectedColor.g) && (currentColor.b == selectedColor.b) && (currentColor.a == selectedColor.a); //,
    
        if (isSame)
        {
            currentColor.rb = 0;
            currentColor.g = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            currentColor.rgb = 1;
        }
    }
    return currentColor;
}

technique Technique1
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
    }
}
```

I belive that color change shouldn't affect checks on next pixel, but maybe I am wrong.

This part is working fine replacing proper pixels, so it's not problem with image resolution or color values on image.

```
        bool isSame = (currentColor.r == selectedColor.r) && (currentColor.g == selectedColor.g) && (currentColor.b == selectedColor.b) && (currentColor.a == selectedColor.a); //,
    
        if (isSame)
        {
            currentColor.rb = 0;
            currentColor.g = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            currentColor.rgb = 1;
        }
```

EDIT:
Solved!
It is that for shader 1 in float2(1, 0) means size of whole texture, so it has to be divided.
Details:
https://community.monogame.net/t/how-do-i-use-shaders-to-create-border-around-a-sprite/11323